# Any ideas on how to make 'the' treated as one, example the appears in position 1 and 3

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a program to report the position of each word in a sentence.  Here is my code:

```
User_input = input('Enter your phone number separated by space >>>')

newlist = (str.split(User_input))

print (newlist)
print ('Length of list',len(newlist))

newset = set(newlist)
print (newset)

shortlist = list(newset)
print (shortlist)

def findit(item,newlist):
    for i in range (len(newlist)):
        if item == newlist[i]:
            print ((newlist[i]),'appears',"in position ",i,"in the list")

for i in range (len(shortlist)):
        findit(shortlist[i],newlist)
```

Output desired:

> What is your sentence?the boy the girl
>
> ['boy', 'girl', 'the']
>
> boy appears in pos 2
>
> girl appears in pos 4
>
> the appears in pos 1
>
> the appears in pos 3

The problem is that I get "the" reported in positions 0 and 2.  How can I get the correct position numbers?

Comment: Why is this tagged iOS? Please tag this properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Also, please note that your input prompt is for a phone number.  You need to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You're printing out the index of the word, rather than the position you want.  In many computer languages, including Python, array / list indices begin at 0.  Look at your actual output (which you didn't bother to provide): *each* of the positions is 1 lower than you want.

Simply add 1 to the subscript:

```
print ((newlist[i]), "appears in position ", i+1, "in the list")
```